# How to insert a field of a procedure result in a variable?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure `dbo.pX` that returns a table with 1 field named `id` and an `INT` in it, that can be equal to 0, or another positive integer. I need to insert this `id` in a variable inside a procedure named `dbo.pY`, to verify if the `id` is greater than 0.

Procedure `dbo.pX`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pX
    @param1 VARCHAR(30)
AS
    DECLARE @id INT;
    -- Some code to change the @id
    SELECT @id AS 'id';
GO
```

What I tried to do in `dbo.pY`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pY
    @param1 VARCHAR(30)
AS
    DECLARE @ret INT;
    SET @ret = (EXECUTE dbo.pX 'something');
    IF ( @ret > 0 ) BEGIN
        -- Some code that uses @ret
    END
GO
```

Any tips or hints to help me find a way to solve it?

Obs: I can't change the procedure `dbo.pX`.

Comment: either you use a scalar function to return or a stored script with output option

Comment: Stored procedure Output parameters: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx . INSERT INTO EXEC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686175/sql-server-insert-into-execute-statement

Comment: INSERT INTO EXEC helped me to reach the solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know the fields that the procedure was bringing me, and I couldn't change that procedure, I solve it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pY
    @param1 VARCHAR(30)
AS
    -- insert the procedure table inside a temporary table
    DECLARE @temp TABLE (id INT);
    INSERT INTO @temp EXECUTE dbo.pX 'something';

    -- insert id that the table brings in a variable
    DECLARE @ret INT;
    SELECT @ret = id FROM @temp;

    IF ( @ret > 0 ) BEGIN
        -- Some code that uses @ret
    END
GO
```

Problem solved :)